# How can I disable Doctrine persist cascade with annotation?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Consider two classes like below:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="notifications")
 */
class Notification {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uid", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $task;

}


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="tasks")
 */
class Task {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uid", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="smallint")
     */
    private $status;

}
```

In my controller I have

```
$task = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Task")->find(1);
$task->setStatus(1);

$notification = new Notification();
$notification->setTask($task);

$em->persist($notification);
$em->flush();
```

My question is how to avoid persisting `task` when I persist `$notification`? with code above it also changes the `task` status to 1.

I know I can do something like below but I was wondering if it is possible to do it with annotation?

```
$em->flush($notification);
```

Why does Doctrine persist the other side of `ManyToOne`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Persist cascading has has nothing to do with that. For example this will still update task:

```
$task = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Task")->find(1);
$task->setStatus(1);
$em->flush();
```

A common misconception is that persisting an entity means it is somehow tagged as being ready to update, that isn't true.

[Persisting an entity](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities) means that entity is now managed by the entity manager.

Changes to any managed entities will be committed on flush, persist doesn't change that if the entity is already managed.

In the case of your task object you already fetched it with the entity manager, so it is considered managed and any updates you make to it will be committed on flush, regardless of whether you call persist on it or not.

In summary, don't update managed entities if you don't want them updated by a global flush, or only call ->flush on entities that you specifically want saved to the database.

More info:

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#synchronization-with-the-database